# Make new instances of a df row if certain column value is missing

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a df like this in python:

| ID | Report Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2021 |
| 1 | 2/1/2021 |
| 1 | 3/1/2021 |
| 2 | NaN |
| 2 | 12/1/2021 |
| 3 | NaN |
| 3 | NaN |

Where some ID's contain all 12 months for report date, some have a few, and some have none associated with them. What I would like to do is make this example df look like:

| ID | Report Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2021 |
| 1 | 2/1/2021 |
| 1 | 3/1/2021 |
| 1 | 4/1/2021 |
| 1 | 5/1/2021 |
| 1 | 6/1/2021 |
| 1 | 7/1/2021 |
| 1 | 8/1/2021 |
| 1 | 9/1/2021 |
| 1 | 10/1/2021 |
| 1 | 11/1/2021 |
| 1 | 12/1/2021 |
| 2 | 1/1/2021 |
| 2 | 2/1/2021 |
| 2 | 3/1/2021 |
| 2 | 4/1/2021 |
| 2 | 5/1/2021 |
| 2 | 6/1/2021 |
| 2 | 7/1/2021 |
| 2 | 8/1/2021 |
| 2 | 9/1/2021 |
| 2 | 10/1/2021 |
| 2 | 11/1/2021 |
| 2 | 12/1/2021 |
| 3 | 1/1/2021 |
| 3 | 2/1/2021 |
| 3 | 3/1/2021 |
| 3 | 4/1/2021 |
| 3 | 5/1/2021 |
| 3 | 6/1/2021 |
| 3 | 7/1/2021 |
| 3 | 8/1/2021 |
| 3 | 9/1/2021 |
| 3 | 10/1/2021 |
| 3 | 11/1/2021 |
| 3 | 12/1/2021 |

Where there are 12 instances of each ID. There is other data attached to this dataframe but I only showed these two columns for simplicity. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Update: So just wanted to clarify that this can be done using dictionaries and for loops but was wondering if there is a pandas function that is easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

NUMBER_OF_IDS = 3
YEAR = 2021

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [
            item
            for sublist in [[i + 1 for _ in range(12)] for i in range(NUMBER_OF_IDS)]
            for item in sublist
        ],
        "Report Date": [
            report_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
            for report_date in pd.date_range(
                start=f"1/1/{YEAR}", end=f"12/31/{YEAR}", freq="MS"
            )
        ]
        * NUMBER_OF_IDS,
    }
)
```

Which provides the desired result:

```py
print(df)

# Output
    ID Report Date
0    1  01/01/2021
1    1  02/01/2021
2    1  03/01/2021
3    1  04/01/2021
4    1  05/01/2021
5    1  06/01/2021
6    1  07/01/2021
7    1  08/01/2021
8    1  09/01/2021
9    1  10/01/2021
10   1  11/01/2021
11   1  12/01/2021
12   2  01/01/2021
13   2  02/01/2021
14   2  03/01/2021
15   2  04/01/2021
16   2  05/01/2021
17   2  06/01/2021
18   2  07/01/2021
19   2  08/01/2021
20   2  09/01/2021
21   2  10/01/2021
22   2  11/01/2021
23   2  12/01/2021
24   3  01/01/2021
25   3  02/01/2021
26   3  03/01/2021
27   3  04/01/2021
28   3  05/01/2021
29   3  06/01/2021
30   3  07/01/2021
31   3  08/01/2021
32   3  09/01/2021
33   3  10/01/2021
34   3  11/01/2021
35   3  12/01/2021
```